# Heroku Timezone Issue with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, momentjs

In my production/heroku app, the code below returns a number of hours that is 7 hours more than the number of hours returned by the code below when it is run in my development/local application.  Why is this?

```
var startDate = moment.tz("2000-01-01", "America/Edmonton").startOf('day');
var endDate   = moment.tz("America/Edmonton");

hourly_count = parseInt(endDate.diff( startDate, 'hours' ) + 1 );
```

Comment: I'm having a similarly bizarre thing happening as well. On my dev machine `moment("APR 27, 2014 12:00PM", ['MMM DD, YYYY hh:mmA']).valueOf()` gives `1398621600000` but on Heroku it gives `1398600000000` to the exact same value.

Comment: @marknadal - that's a different problem.  You are providing the input in terms of local time.  `valueOf` always gives a timestamp that reflects milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which is in terms of UTC.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with Heroku. It automatically calculates it to UTC.

**code**

```
var tms = 1492554237000

console.log(moment(tms).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
console.log(moment.utc(tms).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
```

**local output**

```
2017-04-19 06:23:57
2017-04-18 22:23:57
```

**heroku server output**

```
2017-04-18 22:23:57
2017-04-18 22:23:57
```

I solved it by adjusting timestamp.

```
if (moment().utcOffset() == -0){
    // for server
    tms += 28800000
}
```

**Heroku server output new**

```
2017-04-19 06:23:57
2017-04-19 06:23:57
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.  You are simply observing that the Heroku's *local* time zone happens to be UTC.  The question asked was using a specific *named* time zone with moment-timezone.

Comment: Also, they way you are adjusting is incorrect.  That will choose a different point in time entirely.  What you show in your local output is indeed what I would expect to see from any computer that was in a local time zone 8 hours ahead of UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are specifying a named time zone with moment-timezone, there are only two possible reasons for having different results between local computer and the server:

- The clock is not set correctly on one or both of the devices.  Probably Heroku's clock is fine, so check yours.
- You are not loading any time zone data into moment-timezone.  Older versions of moment-timezone would silently fall back to local time in this case.  Newer versions will give an error.

  You should either use one of the "with-data" distributions, or load time zone data you are interested in via the `moment.tz.add` function.

Chances are, since this question was written in 2014, it was the second problem.

Answer (score -1):

The target machine you're deploying to is probably on UTC, you're going to want to set it or use Moment Timezone.
http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: The question already shows using moment-timezone, by use of the `tz` function.